# Using IAM group as the IAM user for the Cloud SQL database

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-iam

We have a Postgres Database for one of the service in Google Cloud SQL. It is currently using in-built auth using username and password. I wanted to add IAM authentication to it, so I turned on the `cloudsql.iam_authentication` flag.

Now I am trying to add the IAM group that we have as the IAM user using the GCP console. So if the IAM group is `group@iam.example.com` and my GCP account is `user@example.com` which is part of the IAM group, I added `group@iam.example.com` as the IAM user. It asked for Cloud SQL Instance User permission which I gave to the group explicitly (It already had Project Owner permission).
Now when I try to login using `psql` with the following command

```sh
PGPASSWORD=$(gcloud auth print-access-token) psql --host=127.0.0.1 --username=user@example.com --dbname=<DB_NAME>
```

I get the following error -

```sh
psql: error: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "user@example.com"
```

When I use the IAM group email as the username, I receive this -

```sh
psql: error: FATAL:  Cloud SQL IAM user authentication failed for user "group@iam.example.com"
```

When I add my own email as the IAM user even though I don't have any individual permission different than the group and the Cloud Console complains about the lacking Instance User permission, I can login on psql using my own email as the username.

Is there any way I can have just one IAM group as the user and avoid adding all the group members as the IAM users in the Cloud SQL?

Comment: Are you removing the `.gserviceaccount.com` domain suffix on the username when you try to log in?

Comment: @enocom That's just for Service Account as the User. I am not using any Service Account here.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it still helps, but you need to add the **user** (not the group) to the Google Cloud SQL instance users and choose `cloud IAM authentication` method there as it says here it [google docs](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/add-manage-iam-users#creating-a-database-user).
You can't add groups there. The only usage of the group would be to make giving roles to users easier by giving the `Cloud SQL Instance User` role to that group and add users there instead of giving them the role separately.